# Add class to parent if child has content

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a class to the closest  element if a child with class of .present has any html content.

My code at the moment....

```
<article>
  <div class="box">
    <h2>1 dec</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="present">
    <h1>HAS CONTENT</h1>
  </div>
</article>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      if ($(".present").html().length > 0) {
       $(this).parent().addClass('active');
      }
  });
</script>
```

I have tested if condition with a console.log so is being returned as true but active class is not being added to parent element. Can anybody let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You test the condition on `$(".present")` but then ask for `$(this).parent()` instead of `$('.present').parent()`

Comment: why not `$(".present").children().length > 0`?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari This would add active class to every article, i need to add class to only those with content within the .present element

Comment: @reporter How would this help in adding class the the parent article of the .present element?

Comment: Sry, I missunderstood your question.

Comment: @reporter Not to worry, thanks for helping either way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get element that does not have html and then get their parent to *add* class

```
$(".present").filter(function(){
   return $(this).html().trim().length > 0;
}).parent().addClass('active');
```

**Edit**

To add class to `.present` you can skip `.parent()`

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1wax4yn1/)

```
$(".present").filter(function(){
   return $(this).html().trim().length > 0;
}).addClass('active');
```

Comment: Can this be used to check if the element DOES has content?

Comment: It might be a good idea to trim whitespaces first before we add the active class `return $(this).html().trim().length > 0;`

Comment: @Danield - You solved it! Didn't think about whitespace and it being seen as actual content, thanks

Comment: Accepted answer with edits by @Danield, thanks folks